# Breaking a while loop by case in Java

Tags: java

I need to issue break a while loop if a case is matched in a switch statement. The case is as follows: if a user enters either a number less than zero or anything greater than five. I have the switch working most of my cost except the two exceptions Ive mentioned. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Product
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int cntr = 0;
        int product = 0;
        int units = 0;
        double totalcost = 0;
        Scanner MK = new Scanner(System.in);
        cntr=0;
        while (cntr >= 0 && cntr <=5)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Product no.(1-5) or -1 to Quit");
            product = MK.nextInt();
            switch(product) {

            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                product = MK.nextInt();
                double cost = 2.98;
                totalcost = totalcost + cost*product;
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                cntr++;
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                product = MK.nextInt();
                double cost = 4.50;
                totalcost = totalcost + cost*product;
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                cntr++;
            }
            break;
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                product = MK.nextInt();
                double cost = 9.98;
                totalcost = totalcost + cost*product;
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                cntr++;
            }
            break;
            case 4:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                product = MK.nextInt();
                double cost = 4.49;
                totalcost = totalcost + cost*product;
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                cntr++;
            }
            break;
            case 5:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                product = MK.nextInt();
                double cost = 6.87;
                totalcost = totalcost + (cost*product);
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                cntr++;
            }
            case 6:
            {
                System.out.println("Product " + (cntr+1));
                System.out.println("Enter Quantity or -1 to Quit");
                //product = MK.nextInt();
                //double cost = 2.98;
                //totalcost = totalcost + cost*product;
                System.out.println("Current total cost: " + totalcost);
                //cntr++;
            }
            break;
            }
            System.out.println("Total cost-->" +totalcost);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to stop my program when anything less than zero or greater than 5 is entered I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of options:

1. Use a flag that you set when you want the loop to end (in your `default` or `-1` clause), or
2. Use a [*labelled statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) and a *directed* [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15) in your `default` (or `-1`) clause
3. In this *specific* situation where you said you want the entire program to end, you could use [`System.exit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-)

Here's more about option 2:

```
label: while (...) {          // <== Labelled statement
    switch (...) {
        case ...:
            // ...
            break;            // <=== Normal (undirected) break, just exits what
                              //      it's in (switch in this case)
        // ...
        default:
            break label;      // <=== Directed break, exits loop
    }
}
```

It's also handy for nested loops.

---

Side note: There's no need for the `{` and `}` you have surrounding the statements in your `case` clauses. The code for `case` continues until the `break`. (Yes, it's a bit different from other statements.)

---

Side note 2: You've said `Enter Product no.(1-5) or -1 to Quit` in your prompt, but you have cases for the values `1` to **`6`** (inclusive). You probably meant `Enter Product no.(1-**6**) or -1 to Quit`.

Comment: Ive added the following case:    case 6:
   {
       if (product == 6) {
        System.out.println(product);
        
       }
   } just to see if I can get the case to work when the user enters '6', but its not finding the case